# Nginx on SSL (443)

Tags: ssl, https, nginx

My goal is to redirect from port 80 to 443 (force https), but can't manage to get a working https configuration first. I get a 503 Server Error and nothing appears in the logs. I've looked at all the posts on SO and SF, none of them worked (X_FORWARDED_PROTO, X-Forwarded-For headers don't make a difference.). I'm on EC2 behind a load balancer, and so I don't need to use the SSL-related directives as I've configured my certificate on the ELB already. I'm using Tornado for a web server.

Here's the config, if anyone has ideas, thank you!

```
http {
    # Tornado server
    upstream frontends {
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
    }

server {
    listen 443;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    root <redacted>/static;

    location ^~/static/ {
        root <redacted>/current;
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://frontends;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are two different tasks:

If you need to redirect all your http traffic to https, you'll need to create http server in nginx:

```
    server {
      listen 80; 
      server_name example.com;
      return       301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

Second note, if your SSL is terminated at ELB than you dont need ssl enabled nginx server at all. Simply pass traffic from ELB to your server 80 port.

Comment: Yes. I got the redirect part, works fine. As mentioned, it's when it hits 443 that I get the 503.